# Limit the size of the existing and new permalink slugs in Wordpress for SEO

Tags: php, wordpress, seo

I read an article on Google that says for good SEO it is best that the size of the slug in the URL is limited to 5 words.

As I use WordPress the link is assigned automatically to the article title. To redo all the links with just 5 words I would have to spend months editing all the links on my blog.

Would it be possible to do this automatically? There is some function or code for that. I found this code and added it to the function page of my theme and had no results.

See the code:

```
function pm_limit_slugs_length($uri) {
    $max_words = 5; // If any part of URI contains more than 5 words, the slug will be limited to first 5 words
    $new_title = '';
    $slugs = explode('/', $uri);
    
    for($i=0, $count = count($slugs); $i < $count; $i++) {
        $slug = $slugs[$i];
        $words = explode('-', $slug);
        
        $new_title .= "/";
        if(count($words) > $max_words) {
            $new_title .= implode("-", array_slice($words, 0, $max_words));
        } else {
            $new_title .= $slug;
        }
    }
    
    // Remove trailing slashes
    $new_title = trim($new_title, "/");
    
    return $new_title;
}
add_filter('permalink_manager_filter_default_post_uri', 'pm_limit_slugs_length', 99);
add_filter('permalink_manager_filter_default_term_uri', 'pm_limit_slugs_length', 99);
```

I found the code here: https://permalinkmanager.pro/docs/filters-hooks/how-to-limit-the-number-of-words-in-wordpress-permalinks/

How can I use it to limit the Wordpress slug size to 5 words?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First, a note on whether it is worthwhile to do this:**

There are literally 100s of factors that affect SEO. You are not expected to implement all of them, and many will not have a big influence overall. In my opinion, doing this is most likely not going to have any significant effect, and it only makes things more difficult for you.

More importantly, to have any influence on SEO *the slug should include your keywords*, and if you change them programmatically, there is **no way to ensure the slug will include keywords**, so you could even do more harm than good.

FYI, a few versions ago, WP was changed to implement this limit on slugs and then very quickly changed back. That would suggest to me that it might not be very useful or practical.

However if you still want to do this:

**Limiting the words in new slugs**

The code in your question is from this article, right?: [How to limit the number of words in WordPress permalinks or slugs?](https://permalinkmanager.pro/docs/filters-hooks/how-to-limit-the-number-of-words-in-wordpress-permalinks/)

The first example - that you used - is for use with their plugin. The next example (included below) will work in Wordpress without the plugin. This can be added into your functions.php.

UPDATE: I have incorporated the code to [Automatically Remove Short Words From URL](https://www.isitwp.com/better-seo-automatically-remove-short-words-from-url/) into this function to remove short words less than 3 characters, see updated function below.

```
<?php  
/**
 * Trim native slugs
 */
function pm_trim_native_slug($slug, $post_ID, $post_status, $post_type, $post_parent) {
    global $wpdb;

    $max_words = 5; // Limit the number of words to 5; This value can be changed.
    $words = explode('-', $slug);

    /* UPDATED CODE TO REMOVE SHORT WORDS */
    $min_word_length = 2;

    foreach ($words as $k => $word) {
        if (strlen($word) <= $min_word_length)
            unset($words[$k]);
    }
    /* END OF UPDATED CODE FOR SHORT WORDS */

    if(count($words) > $max_words) {
        $slug = implode("-", array_slice($words, 0, $max_words));

        // Make the slugs unique
        $check_sql       = "SELECT post_name FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_name = %s AND ID != %d LIMIT 1";
        $post_name_check = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare($check_sql, $slug, $post_ID));

        if($post_name_check) {
            $suffix = 2;
            do {
                $alt_post_name = _truncate_post_slug($slug, 200 - (strlen($suffix) + 1)) . "-$suffix";
                $post_name_check = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare($check_sql, $alt_post_name, $post_type, $post_ID, $post_parent));
                $suffix++;
            } while ($post_name_check);
            $slug = $alt_post_name;
        }
    }

    return $slug;
}
add_filter('wp_unique_post_slug', 'pm_trim_native_slug', 99, 5);
```

Note that this only works on *new* slugs, you still need to regenerate the old slugs, or write code to go through the existing slugs to update them.

**Updating existing slugs**

You can add this function to your functions.php to get all your slugs, call the function above to generate a new slug, and then update it in the DB:

```
function limit_all_existing_slugs(){
    // get all posts
    $posts = get_posts( array (  'numberposts' => -1 ) );
    
    foreach ( $posts as $post ){

        // create the new slug using the pm_trim_native_slug function 
        $new_slug = pm_trim_native_slug($post->post_name, 
                                        $post->ID, 
                                        $post->post_status, 
                                        $post->post_type, 
                                        $post->post_parent);

        // only do the update if the new slug is different 
        if ( $post->post_name != $new_slug ){
            wp_update_post(
                array (
                    'ID'        => $post->ID,
                    'post_name' => $new_slug
                )
            );
        }
    }
}
```

***Note that the code above is my own and is untested, so make sure you try it out in a test environment first.***

**How to use this function**

To update all the existing slugs, you only want to call this function once on demand, instead of automatically (otherwise it will update the slugs everytime your functions.php loads). You can do that in an external script outside of WP by creating a separate standalone page as follows:

```
<?php
    include('wp-load.php');           //Include the wp-load.php file
    define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);   //We don't need the theme files 

    echo "<p>About to update all slugs...</p>";
    limit_all_existing_slugs();
    echo "<p>...DONE</p>";
?>
```

Comment: thank you for this detailed answer, it's very helpful.

Comment: Thanks for answering me, I tested the code in a test environment where there is only 1 post and the link has not changed.

I don't know if I implemented the code correctly but I added it in the theme function.

Comment: Sorry, the first code worked, only the second failed to regenerate the existing urls

Comment: Where did you call `limit_all_existing_slugs()`? It will not be called automatically - otherwise it would regenerate all of the slugs every time :) You should call it directly to run just once. Depending on your WP skills, the easiest way might be to create a new page template called e.g. "Slug Update" that calls this function, then create a new private page with this template and view it in the browser - that will call the function on demand rather than automatically. Add a few debug lines into the template and code so you can track what is called, just in case there are any problems.

Comment: @MohamedAliO.Ameur thanks :) I always try to give informative answers to explain *why* things work as well as how to do it so that users can learn how to do things, and also so the answer is helpful to future users who might have similar problems but not exactly the same - the explanation can help them tweak it to their requirements.

Comment: Sorry, should I create a page for example as teste.php and add just this code on it? then execute it in the browser?

Comment: @resumo Yes, you need to execute it in the browser in its own page, so that it only runs when you load that page. You can do it in a standalone page (but the function uses WP functions so you need to include all the WP header info manually), or the easiest way is to create a page template and use it on a page in WP, and execute it in the browser.

Comment: Now I'm confused, the second code function limit_all_existing_slugs needs is in the theme function or just on the example page?

Comment: @resumo It doesn't need the theme files, but it need access to WPs functions and database. You can create a page to run it in 2 ways: 1. Use a standalone page like in the answer, or 2. Create a page template in your theme and use it. It doesn't matter which you do, it just depends on which way you find easier to do.

Comment: I created the page and put only the second code on it and gave it the name of slug-update.php and executed it and had no effect on the existing urls. Could you give me an example of what this page would look like?

Comment: Ok, now it worked, I left the 2 codes in the function of the theme and used the third code to create a page and call the regeneration when necessary.

But I have 1 more doubt.

Would it be possible to also limit small words by 5 words? and leave words longer than 4 letters?

Comment: Making it clearer, this link https://permalinkmanager.pro/docs/filters-hooks/how-to-limit-the-number-of-words-in-wordpress-permalinks/

In addition to limiting words to 5 words and leaving only words greater than 3 letters?

Excluding words less than 4 letters: how, to, the, of, in

The link above would look like this

https://permalinkmanager.pro/docs/filters-hooks/limit-number-words-wordpress-permalinks/

Comment: I found here https://www.isitwp.com/better-seo-automatically-remove-short-words-from-url/ a way to remove short words but I don't know if you can use it with your code

Comment: @resumo Yes, you need to keep the functions in your functions.php so your page can find them. I've updated the code to remove short words before creating the 5-word slug.  Its not tested but it should work. It checks for words of 2 chars or less, but I created a variable that you can change to whatever length you want. I think that should be everything you need! :)

Comment: Hello again, I don't know what I did wrong, but I was testing different numbers of 5 and switching to 4, 3 2 and 1, when I went back to 5 letters here $ max_words = 5; he didn't return and got stuck at 1

What do you think I did wrong? I think the page I created to regenerate stopped working

Comment: @resumo If you have used the function to replace the slugs in the database with a one-word slug during your testing, then running this function to reduce the number of words to 5 won't do anything, as the slug is already less than 5 words. If you go back to your original data from the production version, you will be able to start again with the full slug.

Comment: Yes, but shouldn't the page to regenerate the existing urls work?

Comment: Sorry, the code works perfectly for new links, but I would also need the old links to be changed.

In the beginning I was able to regenerate all the links in my tests, but after changing it to 1 word and back to 5 words it didn't regenerate and was stuck in 5.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220238/discussion-between-fluffykitten-and-resumo).