# Limit the size of existing permalink slugs only on specific custom post type in Wordpress for SEO

Tags: php, wordpress, seo, permalinks, slug

Below are the codes i found on: [Limit the size of the existing and new permalink slugs in Wordpress for SEO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63525271/limit-the-size-of-the-existing-and-new-permalink-slugs-in-wordpress-for-seo) which were very helpful but i still need a little further help please.

**CODE 1 below:** Help limit the size of permalink slug to 5 words for new post only, it does not affect existing post:

```
<?php  
/**
 * Trim native slugs
 */
function pm_trim_native_slug($slug, $post_ID, $post_status, $post_type, $post_parent) {
    global $wpdb;

    $max_words = 5; // Limit the number of words to 5; This value can be changed.
    $words = explode('-', $slug);

    /* UPDATED CODE TO REMOVE SHORT WORDS */
    $min_word_length = 2;

    foreach ($words as $k => $word) {
        if (strlen($word) <= $min_word_length)
            unset($words[$k]);
    }
    /* END OF UPDATED CODE FOR SHORT WORDS */

    if(count($words) > $max_words) {
        $slug = implode("-", array_slice($words, 0, $max_words));

        // Make the slugs unique
        $check_sql       = "SELECT post_name FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_name = %s AND ID != %d LIMIT 1";
        $post_name_check = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare($check_sql, $slug, $post_ID));

        if($post_name_check) {
            $suffix = 2;
            do {
                $alt_post_name = _truncate_post_slug($slug, 200 - (strlen($suffix) + 1)) . "-$suffix";
                $post_name_check = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare($check_sql, $alt_post_name, $post_type, $post_ID, $post_parent));
                $suffix++;
            } while ($post_name_check);
            $slug = $alt_post_name;
        }
    }

    return $slug;
}
add_filter('wp_unique_post_slug', 'pm_trim_native_slug', 99, 5);
```

**CODE 2 below:** Help limit the size of permalink slug to 5 words for existing post with the help of code 3 below:

```
function limit_all_existing_slugs(){
    // get all posts
    $posts = get_posts( array (  'numberposts' => -1 ) );
    
    foreach ( $posts as $post ){

        // create the new slug using the pm_trim_native_slug function 
        $new_slug = pm_trim_native_slug($post->post_name, 
                                        $post->ID, 
                                        $post->post_status, 
                                        $post->post_type, 
                                        $post->post_parent);

        // only do the update if the new slug is different 
        if ( $post->post_name != $new_slug ){
            wp_update_post(
                array (
                    'ID'        => $post->ID,
                    'post_name' => $new_slug
                )
            );
        }
    }
}
```

**CODE 3 below:** Is to call the function in code 2 by adding it to template and fire it on demand, this will make code 2 work for existing posts slug:

```
<?php
    include('wp-load.php');           //Include the wp-load.php file
    define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);   //We don't need the theme files 

    echo "<p>About to update all slugs...</p>";
    limit_all_existing_slugs();
    echo "<p>...DONE</p>";
?>
```

**NOW MY QUESTIONS WHERE I NEED HELP:**

The above codes were helpful, but I only need to reduce the permalink slug size of a specific custom post type, called: **job_listing** without affecting other post types. I was only able to achieve this on new post slug by placing the entire codes in **code 1 above** in this if statement:

```
if ( get_post_type() === 'job_listing' ) { 

}
```

But this method did not work for me in **code 2** for existing post slug. Code 2 only worked for WordPress default blog post type and not my intended custom post type called: **job_listing**

How can I change the permalink slug for existing post only for custom post type: **job_listing** using **code 2** above the same way I did for new permalink slug in **code 1**?

Sorry for my long write-up, this is the only way I can get people to understand me as this question is coming from another discussion.

Thanks.

Comment: `get_posts` takes a `post_type` parameter.

Comment: Thanks **CBrone** for your willingness to help. In line 3, I changed `get_posts` to `post_type` as advised, but unfortunately it did not work. It still does not affect custom post type.  Is there any other part of the code where i need to make this change besides line 3?

Comment: _"n line 3, I changed get_posts to post_type as advised"_ - huh? No one advised _that_. I did not say, use a different method, I said it takes additional parameters.

Comment: Maybe i did not understand your answer quite well. Can you please help with a more direct and explained solution as i am not a pro?

Comment: Go check the documentation. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/parse_query/

Comment: Thanks CBrone. All the codes above were given by somebody in another discussion and it has helped so many people alot. All i need is a little modification to enable me limit old permalink slug for  a custom post only. I think you should also be kind enough to help me modify the code a bit to achieve that rather than directing me to documentation link even when i have already said that i am not a pro.